# function not defined when called

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

i have a function that returns a list which i would like to use within another function, when i call the function it says that it is not defined, is there something wrong with my code or method of calling?

this is function i am returning a list from.

```
def KingMoves(self, rows, columns):
    FinalMove = []
    FinalMove.append(((rows - 1),(columns))) # (left 1)
    FinalMove.append(((rows + 1),(columns))) # (right 1)
    FinalMove.append(((columns + 1),(rows))) # (up 1)
    FinalMove.append(((row + 1),(columns + 1))) # (right 1) (up 1) -- Diagonals for king only
    FinalMove.append(((row - 1),(columns + 1))) # (left 1)(up 1)
    FinalMove.append(((row + 1),(columns - 1))) # (right 1)(down 1)
    FinalMove.append(((row - 1),(columns - 1))) # (left 1)(down 1)

    return FinalMove;
```

this is where i attempt to use the list returned list.

```
def UserInput(self):

    global AllPieces

    TheKingMoves = KingMoves()

    OnGoing = True
```

this is the error i am receiving:

```
NameError: name 'KingMoves' is not defined
```

i have tried to pass the Kingmoves paramenters but get the same result

Comment: `self.KingMoves`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @internet_user thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `TheKingMoves = self.KingMoves(rows, cols)`.

Calling `self.KingMoves()` will raise an error since `KingMoves` has required positional arguments you haven't supplied.

As an aside, before going any further in python, please read the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It'll help people understand your code faster in the future.